# Android Annotations framework is not generating anything

Tags: android-annotations

I am trying to use Android annotations in Android studio.
In my libs folder in my project , I'm putting "androidannotations-api-3.3.2.jar"
(not using gradle for annotation library)

Thought ,there was not any compilation issue,I could not find the generated _ files for my Activity.

In AndroidMenifest.xml also

"MainActivity_" is not able to resolved.

Comment: You should use Gradle. The guide is [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/IntelliJIDEA) for no-Gradle configuration, but it is really complicated, and also you loose the ability to easily move the project.

Comment: @WonderCsabo   I followed the steps in your guide link. But still I'm not able to open "Open File -> Project structure -> Modules -> Sources, then right click the generated folder and select Source"   in your link https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/IntelliJIDEA         Can you please help me how to generate the   generated annotation files ( _  suffixed)   files.

Comment: I really, really suggest to use Gradle... It is easier to setup, it is the standard, your project can be ported, etc.
Also i do not know what is your problem. I just tried and i can open the window in the guide.